# how to use Servicemix to make SOAP Web Services comunicate

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-servicemix

I want to build a system made by several WebServices that exchange SOAP messages through Servicemix. These WSs are not local, but they are remote. So my idea is providing Servicemix as a service itself, and all the others will send message to it. It will be Servicemix to deliver soap messages to the right Service, log and notify the success/fail of the delivery.

Is this doable? Is this a correct use of Servicemix? I can't find a good example or tutorial with this configuration.

I can build WSs easily starting from a wsdl, using the Maven archetype

`servicemix-cxf-wsdl-first-osgi-bundle`

and they can be deployed on Servicemix... but they will be all local! I want to make remote WSs exchanging messages through a shared bus.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is essentially the pattern for ServiceMix. Much of what you are looking for in terms of mediation and routing is realized through Apache Camel. You would need to host the remote web services in a separate web container, such as Tomcat or Jetty. Next, you would implement service endpoints as OSGi bundles that are deployed to ServiceMix. These OSGi bundles expose your service interface. When a SOAP request comes in to the OSGi bundle endpoint, you can then use Camel routing rules to route the SOAP message to the appropriate remote web service endpoint.

For some examples of this, I recommend checking out the JBoss Fuse documentation:

http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/resources/

Fusesource used to be a support organization around ServiceMix; however, they have since been acquired by RedHat. You will find much better documentation and examples over the ServiceMix documentation itself.

Comment: thank you @MichaelHoffman, now it's much more clearer. So, I guess Servicemix let different services (soap, rest, ..) communicate, implementing the OSGI bundles as needed. About the example, do you mean the _Servicemix 4 example payment service_ ? I'm checking the documentation you pointed, but it assumes the use of the Fuse IDE. I would need an example with ServiceMix

Comment: Fuse is essentially servicemix; though, not the IDE itself. I don't have an example right now to give you. I was hoping that the Fuse examples may give you some inspiration.

Comment: ok, thank you for now then. At least, I understood the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/how-does-camel-compare-to-servicemix.html) for the routing, transforming etc.:

> Camel is smart routing and mediation engine which implements the Enterprise Integration Patterns and is designed to be used either inside an ESB like ServiceMix, in a Message Broker like ActiveMQ or in a smart endpoint or web services framework like CXF. ServiceMix is an ESB, a JBI container and an integration platform. So they both address different needs though they are both designed to work great together.

Comment: So I should use Camel to make the OSGI bundles to deploy on ServiceMix, that will redirect messages to remote WS through routes. Am I right?  thank you

Comment: @DeLac Camel routes will be deployed as OSGI bundles; Camel is not a build tool, you don't use Camel to make (= create?) bundles. And yes, Camel routes redirect the messages.